# Name for Euclid, Book III, Proposition 21?

Tags: terminology, euclidean-geometry

Euclid's Proposition 21 in Book III is something I learned in 11th grade.

**Is there a standard name for it?**

http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookIII/propIII21.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you mean the [inscribed angle theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem)?

In French, it's called [arc capable](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_capable), which is similar to the Spanish and Portuguese [arco capaz](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arco_capaz).

Comment: See also http://physicsnapkins.wordpress.com/2009/11/20/arco-capaz-is-there-an-english-word/.

Comment: I see that the French Wikipedia article titled "arc capable" links to a section titled "Théorème de l'angle inscrit" in another article: http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_l%27angle_inscrit_et_de_l%27angle_au_centre#Th.C3.A9or.C3.A8me_de_l.27angle_inscrit

Comment: In German, there's the word "Ortsbogen" (with a capital initial letter because it's a noun) that seems to refer to the arc considered in this theorem.

Comment: On closer inspection, it seems that the French phrase "arc capable" is exactly synonymous with the German word "Ortsbogen".

Comment: Here are three related propositions: (1) As the point M moves along an arc of a circle from A to B, the angle AMB remains constant. (2) If M is on an arc of a circle from A to B, then the angle AMB is half of the angle AOB, where O is the center. (3) If the point M follows a curve so located that the angle AMB remains constant, then the curve it follows is an arc of a circle.

Answer (score 3):

I recently came across the name "Bow tie lemma" for III.21 and "Star Trek lemma" for the preceding proposition III.20.  Although they are new names, not yet standard, they are memorable.